# Can't get connect-flash to work with express.js on redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Ok for some reason the session flash works when I `res.render()`, but when I try to set the session flash and then redirect, it doesn't display. The problem is below in the contact method in the `else` clause)...

This is what is logged to the console during the redirect:

`{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{ info: [ 'Thanks we will return your message soon' ] }
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}`

As you can see, the message is definitely in there, but it looks like it's getting replaced with an empty object.

Here is my code:

`app.js`

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');

// Grab sessions
var sessionFlash = function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = req.flash();
  console.log(res.locals.messages);
  next();
}

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(viewHelpers());
  app.use(express.bodyParser({ uploadDir : './' }));

  app.use(expressValidator);
  app.use(express.methodOverride());

  app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: config.secret,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    },
    store: new MongoStore(config.db)
  }));

  app.use(flash());
  app.use(sessionFlash);

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

`views/layout.jade`

```
- if (typeof message !== 'undefined')
  =message
```

`controllers/index.js`

```
function controllers(params) {

  controllers.contact = function(req, res) {
    if (errors) {
      // This works as intended
      req.flash('info', 'Please fix the errors below.');

      res.render('contact', {
        title : 'Contact -',
        message: req.flash('info'),
        errors: errors,
        params: params
      });
      return;
    } else {
      // This doesn't work
      req.flash('info', 'Thanks we will return your message soon');
      res.redirect('/');
    }
   };
   return controllers
  }

  module.exports = controllers;
```

Comment: I'm having this problem too.  I have a `req.get('/')`, and if I call my routes before `use.flash`, I get a `req.flash is not a function` error.  By logging the `req.path`, it seems like most of the requests are for static files, and the flash message is sent to one of them.  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are redirecting to '/', which server does not respond to.

You don't have `app.get('/', function(req, res){...});` in your app.js

Flash messages are messages that are stored on the server for the duration between two requests from the same client, and thus are only available in the next request. The flash does not show because your `res.redirect('/');` does nothing.

Comment: That's part of the reason I have `app.use(sessionflash)` in my app.config since I want that to be hit on every web request (as it spits out whatever is in the session flashes).

Comment: Btw I do have app.get('/'), which is in another routes file, which I export to app.js but that doesn't matter because all routes should be hitting that `sessionFlash` middleware I mentioned in my previous comment. Look at the log I posted -- it's in there, it's just being overwritten.

Comment: Routes like '/' requires app.use(app.router); and must be before app.use(flash()); Else if its working correctly, maybe your '/' page is ignoring the flash message.